# Zabbix JMX monitoring host is not reachable

Tags: java, jmx, zabbix

I am trying to use Zabbix monitor a Java application by JMX interface. I started java application with command like below:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP \
 -jar $MY_JAR
```

I am able to connect to it using visualVM remote monitor by adding $HOST_IP:9999. However, I cannot connect to it in the Zabbix JMX interface with the same setting.
Is there any other setting we need to do in the Zabbix or do we need to run any agent in the java application server? Thanks.

Comment: Not on the Java App Server but in Zabbix, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/concepts/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that I need to enable and configure the Java gateway in the Zabbix server as [zabbix server docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql/) by setting up the following variables:

```
ZBX_JAVAGATEWAY_ENABLE=true
ZBX_JAVAGATEWAY=zabbix-java-gateway
ZBX_JAVAGATEWAYPORT=10052
ZBX_STARTJAVAPOLLERS=5
```

Thanks

Comment: You saved me bro!